# Spring Security OAuth2 Credentiais through header

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Well, i'm creating a Authorization Server using Spring Security OAuth Project, this is my configurer class:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("clientid")
                .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "client_credentials", "password")
                .scopes("myscope")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/oauth/login/client-app");
    }

    /**
     * Precisamos para uso do Password Flow
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).
                tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("ABC");
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }
}
```

Well, when I try to retrieve the Access Token i need pass "clientid" and "secret" through headers, like this (works very well returning the JWT Token):

```
curl clientid:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -dgrant_type=client_credentials -dscope=myscope
```

But if I try this:

```
 curl localhost:8080/oauth/token -dgrant_type=client_credentials -dscope=transferir-valores -dclient_id=clientid -dclient_secret=secret
```

I got Unauthorized message.

Answer (score 0):

The second request is incorrect and that is why you're getting an unauthorized message.
Check the following excerpt from the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1):

> Clients in possession of a client password MAY use the HTTP Basic
> authentication scheme as defined in [RFC2617] to authenticate with the
> authorization server.  The client identifier is encoded using the
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

> Alternatively, the authorization server MAY support including the client credentials in the request-body.

> Including the client credentials in the request-body using the two parameters is NOT RECOMMENDED

It is recommended to send client credentials as basic auth (encode credentials to base64 as add it to headers). Something like this:

`curl -X POST \ http://localhost:8443/auth-service/oauth/token \ -H 'Authorization: Basic VEVTVF9TRVJWSUNFOnBhc3N3b3Jk' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ -d grant_type=client_credentials`